# Why is Gradle unable to access gradle.properties?

Tags: gradle, groovy, properties, configuration

In my users home directory "C:/Users/USERNAME" I have created a gradle.properties file with the following content:

```
signing.keyId=YourKeyId
signing.password=YourPublicKeyPassword
signing.secretKeyRingFile=PathToYourKeyRingFile

ossrhUsername=your-jira-id
ossrhPassword=your-jira-password
```

I am supposed to be able to access this in the gradle build file.  According to [this Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties) I am supposed to be able to use these just by mentioning their identifier.   So I made a build.gradle file with the following.

```
println "ossrhUsername: "+ossrhUsername
println "ossrhPassword: "+ossrhPassword
```

When I run this, it fails, complaining that it can not find a property `ossrhUsername`.   I don't know what to do since the official documentation says this should work, and it gives an example that does not work for me, I can't figure what is wrong.  Here is the output

```
d:\build\gradleplay>gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\build\gradleplay\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleplay'.
> Could not get unknown property 'ossrhUsername' for root project 'gradleplay' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Another source said that findProperty should work like this:

```
println "ossrhUsername: "+findProperty("ossrhUsername")
println "ossrhPassword: "+findProperty("ossrhPassword")
```

This runs, but the value returned from findProperty is null.

Another source said that these values can be found as a map on the project object, and insisted that this should work:

```
println "ossrhUsername: "+project.properties["ossrhUsername"]
println "ossrhPassword: "+project.properties["ossrhPassword"]
```

This runs as well, but I get null for both of the values.  I suspect for some reason the gradle system is not looking in the c:/Users/USERNAME folder and is not reading the file.   Any way you can think of to figure why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer is that gradle.properties is NOT placed in the user home directory, but instead placed in a folder UNDER the user home directory.

Instead of

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\gradle.properties
```

It must be placed in

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\gradle.properties
```

The .gradle folder is confusingly named GRADLE_USER_HOME and should not be confused with USER_HOME.   Given the number of questions I found about this, I would conclude this is a very poor naming convention.  Well, two hours wasted on that.

This was some confusing documentation at [SonaType site](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-gradle/):

[image]

I don't know how to tell them that this instruction is incorrect (except, of course, if you set the environment variable to a non-default value.)

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home

Comment: Yeah that sonatype document is plain wrong. I wouldn't say it's poor naming on gradle's part